# Number of shortest polygonal paths joining vertices of chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

In William Feller's probability book (the first of the two part series), the following example is given (page 36)

> The number of shortest polygonal paths (with horizontal and vertical segments) joining two diagonally opposite vertices of a chessboard equals $\binom{16}{8} = 12,870$.

No further explanation was given, and I wanted to justify this, but I came to a different conclusion. My thoughts are as follows: starting from the lower left square, any valid path to the upper right square can be described by a string describing $7$ right moves (say R) and $7$ up moves (say U). There is a bijection between these strings and valid paths. The amount of such strings is equal to the amount of unordered collections of $7$ out of $14$ digits, since any such string can be described completely by the positions of the U's (or, same thing, the R's) in the string. This gives me the result $\binom{14}{7} = 3,432$. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Mark Bennet already pointed it out. Additionally, this type of "rectangular grid walk question" is very common. See https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction/. If you are interested, there are harder questions involving restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going from corner to corner and therefore from vertex to vertex, the number of steps in each direction is $8$ rather than $7$ and you get the advertised answer by your method.

Comment: I interpreted it as the paths being the squares themselves, not on their edges; thank you for your answer.